# PowerShell: Copy the content of one file to other several files with regex

Tags: powershell, terminal

people. I have in Folder1 a html file named **file1.html** that has this content:

**Folder1**

```html
<!-- FLAGS_1 -->
      <div class="cautareField">
          <div align="right">
             <a href="https://neculaifantanaru.com/izolarea-cercetatorului-in-cursa-lunga-a-leadershipului.html">&nbsp; <a href="https://neculaifantanaru.com/fr/l-isolement-du-chercheur-dans-le-marathon-de-leadership.html">&nbsp; <a href="https://neculaifantanaru.com/en/the-flashing-of-a-mind-inclined-towards-the-infinite.html">
         </div>
        </div>
<!-- FLAGS -->
```

**Folder2** (example of the content of all files, so only the links are different)

```html
<!-- FLAGS_1 -->
      <div class="cautareField">
          <div align="right">
             <a href="https://neculaifantanaru.com/index.html">&nbsp; <a href="https://neculaifantanaru.com/fr/index.html">&nbsp; <a href="https://neculaifantanaru.com/en/index.html">
         </div>
        </div>
<!-- FLAGS -->
```

So the content between `<!-- FLAGS_1 -->` to `<!-- FLAGS -->` in **file1.html** needs be copied in all html files in folder 2 at the same `<!-- FLAGS_1 -->` to `<!-- FLAGS -->` place

Comment: "in the same place" - what does that mean? Can you show an example file from `folder2` and show which position in the document you consider the same place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sh
# Sourcefile contains text to insert
$sourcefile = "c:/Folder1/file1.html"
# Get content to insert
$sourceContent = Get-Content -Path $sourcefile  -Raw
# Get target files
$destinationFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path "c:/Folder2" -Filter "*.html";  
# Do for each file in destination folder
foreach ($file in $destinationFiles) {
    # Prepare regex
    $contentToInsert = [regex]::match($sourceContent,'(?ms)<!-- FLAGS_1 -->(.+)<!-- FLAGS -->').value
    # Get content of destination file
    $destinationContent = Get-Content $file.FullName -Raw
    # Replace the text in destination file content
    $destinationContent = $destinationContent -replace '(?ms)<!-- FLAGS_1 -->(.+)<!-- FLAGS -->',$contentToInsert
    # Write back destination file
    Set-Content -Path $file.FullName -Value $destinationContent -Encoding UTF8
} #end foreach file
```

Thank you, AndreasBaumgarten, who [helped me here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/372196/powershell-copy-the-content-of-one-file-to-other-s.html).